# Collectionview inside tableview cell with 1 data source

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to put collection view inside tableview cell. Every tableview cell contains 2 collectionviewCell. Let say I have 8 pic in my data model, I want the collection view looks like the image. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: what exactly the problem is? you can't make it on storyboard?

Comment: I already put collection view on tableview in storyboard, i think the right question is, how to use it with 1 data source? I mean img0-img1 and img2-img3 aren't in the same tableViewcell @heximal

Comment: Keep your images in an array or dictionary and fetch the one that's needed from willDisplayCell...

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of Using Collection View inside tableview , Use only collection view  with vertical scroll and in the method

```
  #pragma mark ------------Collection View Delegates-----------------
 override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: 
        UICollectionView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, 
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, 
    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> 
         UICollectionViewCell! {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier,
         forIndexPath: indexPath) as !MyCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    let image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageView.image = image

    return cell
}
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(_collectionViewToAddImages.frame.size.width/2, _collectionViewToAddImages.frame.size.height/2);
    }
```

In this way you will have view like this, just add the pading and you will get the results [image]

Comment: the thing is i need to show background image in every row (look at orange rectangle in my question)  @Hilman

Comment: I tried converting my code into swift....i didn't work with swift so much so please mind if there is any syntax error.